# Create nine-patch from bitamp - and getting new adjust bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

I'm tring to download an image from the net, and to convert it to ninepatch format, how I select the stretchable pixels is out of scope for this thread.

I'm trying to use [gist solution](https://gist.github.com/briangriffey/4391807) but I couldn't get it to work.

This is the source code:

```
NinePatchDrawable np = createNinePathWithCapInsets(res, bitmap, top,left, bitmap.getWidth() - right, bitmap.getHeight() - bottom, null);
```

and to get the resulted bitmap:

```
Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
//np.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
np.draw(canvas);
canvas.drawBitmap(outputBitmap, width, height, new Paint());
```

The returned bitmap doesn't contain the source bitmap and looks just like 4 segmentations(rect seg').

I could find any other to achive that goal, even not using OpenGL

The resulted image is:

[image]

Comment: I'm adding the image..

Comment: nice pic, whats wrong with it?

Comment: My source image is totally different(I cannot upload it), it's a transparent image with big icon in the bottom right corner, I wan't to streach its transformed pixels and so the icons won't get streached. No, as you can see the icon doean't shown at all and there're those strange colors..

Comment: there should not be canvas.drawBitmap, np.draw(canvas) is enough

Comment: @pskink you're right, but also without this line nothing is changed

Comment: place your .9.png file in a. drawable folder then call BitmapFactory.decodeResource and finally call on resulted Bitmap.getNinePatchChunk ajd compare that byte[] with your solution

Comment: I don't have a 9.png file, I'm trying to convert bitmap that I got from the net into a NinePatchDrawable, and then use it to draw the bitmap as a ninepatch(according to the params I'm setting in the buffer)

Comment: so create one, you will then see how the chunk should look like

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static byte[] getChunk(int xs, int xe, int ys, int ye) {
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(84).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    b.put((byte) 1); // wasDeserialized
    b.put((byte) 2); // numXDivs
    b.put((byte) 2); // numYDivs
    b.put((byte) 9); // numColors
    b.putInt(0);     // UNKNOWN
    b.putInt(0);     // UNKNOWN
    b.putInt(0);     // paddingLeft
    b.putInt(0);     // paddingRight
    b.putInt(0);     // paddingTop
    b.putInt(0);     // paddingBottom
    b.putInt(0);     // UNKNOWN
    b.putInt(xs);    // segX start
    b.putInt(xe);    // segX end
    b.putInt(ys);    // segY start
    b.putInt(ye);    // segY end
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        b.putInt(1);     // NO_COLOR
    }
    return b.array();
}
```

you can use it in NinePatchDrawable constructor (Bitmap, byte[], Rect, String)