# Is it possible to load 9-patch images from external resource?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have an application that want to load some images from web, My question is that can i load a  9-patch image from web ? or it only must be in a resource folder of my app ?
I searched a lot and i found [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/7qoymg/working-9-patch-images-from-assets-or-any-other-location) that say its not possible :

> However, (uncrunched) 9-patch images created with draw9patch tool will
>   not work if you try to load them from assets or any other internal or
>   external location. You have to put them in one of resources drawable
>   directory.

But i dont find any documentation that confirm it :/

Comment: you can do that, but you need to provide a binary `chunk` parameter to `NinePatchDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, byte[] chunk, Rect padding, String srcName)chunk)` constructor, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19982411/2252830) for example

Comment: also, [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#57) you have detailed info about the `chunk`

Comment: Thanks , i will check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem wuth this awesome library :
decide to post it maybe resolve problem of others
https://github.com/Anatolii/NinePatchChunk